# Content spinning - Calculate the number of combinations in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to calculate the number of combinations that it is possible to do in content spinning.

I do it in dart for an application coded with Flutter

For the following character string:
{hello | hi} {world | everyone}

There are 4 possible combinations.

For the following one:
{hi | {john | jane}}

There are 3 of them.

I succeed for the following character string:
{hello | hi} {world | everyone}

with the following agorithm:

```
    final String pattern = "{ hello|hi } { world|everyone }";
  
    RegExp regExp = RegExp(r"\{([^\{\}]*)\}");

    final Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = regExp.allMatches(pattern);
  
    List<int> nMaches = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      final List<String> pin = matches.elementAt(i).group(1)!.split("|");
      nMaches.add(pin.length);
    }

    int possibilities= nMaches.fold(1, (previous, current) => previous * current);
  
    print(possibilities);
```

But I'm having trouble designing the same code for the following string:
{hi | {john | jane}}

Could you help me ?
thanks in advance

Comment: I would only see 2 possible combinations for the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```dart
int getVariantsCount(String pattern) {
    int count(
      String partialPattern,
      int from,
      int accumulator,
    ) {
      var endGroupIndex = 0;
      var stop = false;

      for (var i = 0; i < partialPattern.length; i++) {
        if (partialPattern[i] == '}') {
          if (i == partialPattern.length - 1 || partialPattern[i + 1] == '{') {
            endGroupIndex = i + 1;
            stop = i == partialPattern.length - 1;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      var substring = partialPattern.substring(0, endGroupIndex);
      print(substring);

      final inGroup = substring.codeUnits.fold(
          1,
          (previousValue, element) => element == '|'.codeUnits[0]
              ? (previousValue + 1)
              : previousValue);

      if (stop) {
        return accumulator * inGroup;
      }

      return count(
        partialPattern.substring(endGroupIndex),
        endGroupIndex,
        accumulator * inGroup,
      );
    }

    return count(pattern.replaceAll(' ', ''), 0, 1);
  }
```

Some tests:

```dart
  print(getVariantsCount('{hello | hi}') == 2);
  print(getVariantsCount('{nice | good {job | goal}}') == 3);
  print(getVariantsCount('{hello}{world|everyone}') == 2);
  print(getVariantsCount('{ hello|hi } { world|everyone }') == 4);
  print(getVariantsCount('{ hello|hi|ola } { world|everyone }') == 6);
  print(getVariantsCount('{hello | hi} {nice | good {job | goal}}') == 6);
  print(
      getVariantsCount('{hello | hi} {cute | nice | good {job | goal}}') == 8);
  print(
      getVariantsCount('{hello | hi | ok} {cute | nice | good {job | goal}}') ==
          12);
  print(getVariantsCount('{hello} {cute | nice | good {job | goal}}') == 4);
  print(getVariantsCount('{hello | hi} {cute | nice | good} {job | goal}') == 12);
```

Comment: Thank you,
Currently I cannot calculate this type of combination

{hello | hi} {nice | good {job | goal}}

which should be 6 as a result.
```
{nice | good {job | goal}} = 3
{hello | hi} = 2
```

2 * 3 = 6

I'm 3 days away from testing in all directions, I can't do it :(

Comment: @Nicolas I just updated my answer.